# В Firefox при запуске document.write не срабатывает POST

Tags: javascript, firefox

В проекте MVC при нажатии на *submit* происходит *POST*, для того что пользователь во время сохранения данных ничего не нажимал сделана заставка `document.write` содержащая `<div>` с заставкой: *"Бла бла сохраняется ждите"*.

Во всех браузерах все отрабатывает норм, происходит пост, во время поста заставка, а как все сохранилось - страница обновляется и `document.write` исчезает.

Проблема заключается в том, что в *Firefox* при появлении заставки при нажатии на *submit* не происходит *post* и прога просто висит бесконечно крутя заставку на экране. Как только убираю заставку из кода все работает и *post* происходит.

Помогите решить проблему, в чем ошибка: в самом Firefox  или `document.write`? и чем можно альтернативно заменить???

Comment: вообще _document.write_ не рекомендуют к использованию. В любом случае лучше добавить [mcve]. А так же не стоит откатывать исправленное форматирование

Answer (score 2):

Появление "заставки" лучше всего реализовать через стили. Делаем на странице заготовленный контейнер:

```html
<div id="saving-dialog" style="display: none">
  ...
</div>
```

Для показа меняем ему стиль:

```js
document.getElementById("saving-dialog").style.display = "block";
```

Достоинств по сравнению с document.write - море:

1. Верстка лежит среди прочей верстки. Нет нужны запихивать HTML-тэги внутрь строковых литералов;
2. Для того, чтобы увидеть в процессе верстки сообщение на странице - достаточно поменять ему стиль из инструментов разработчика в браузере, нет нужды прибегать к хитрым трюкам;
3. При показе такого заготовленного диалога браузеру нет нужды парсить страницу заново;
4. Не используется устаревший метод;
5. Такой способ точно не собьет submit формы.